# Laravel add additional information for user

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel for a little app. In this app I added the auth things of Laravel (verison 5.3), so I automatically got a possibility to register and log in.

So what I got now are a few controllers, 2 vies and a table users, with name, email and password and a unique auto incrementing primary key. What I want now, is to make the logged in user able to add additional information, like City, Street, Telephone, etc..

I don't want to make the user able to add this directly at register. What I want instead, is, that if the user is logged in, he can navigate to a view (lets say its reachable through the route `/changeUserData`. There, he can find a form. In this form, initally there is no data, he can enter everything (as I said, like City, Street, etc.) and save information. I'd like to save this information in another table in the db, called `user_infos`, with several columns containing City, Street, Telephone, etc. I'd like to be able to have this second table without a primary key, but with a foreign key - the primary key of the users table.

So the process would be, navigates to the view with the form /changeUserData. Then there is a lookup in the table user_infos, if the logged in user already saved information there. Therefore, I'd need to look up the primary key of the user via the email-adress (unique as well), which is stored in `{{auth::user()->email}}`. If he didn't save any information there yet, then he gets a blank form, where he can enter everything. Clicking on save, makes a new entry in the `user_infos` table, containing all information entered, as well as the foreign key got from the `users` table. If there is already an entry for the user, the information should be already shown in the form inputs, and the user should also be able to edit the information and save the updated information.

I know this was much text. Basically what I need to know is how to really do the database things. So how can I lookup the primary key (respectively the column with the name `id`) with the email-adress. How can I then create a new row in the other table, containing this id and the information entered? And how can I get the information from the database then to add in to the form inputs? Basically what I found is [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent), but I doesn't seem to understand it. Can anybody give me an example of how I can do this?

Please note, that I'm completely new to Laravel, as well as this hole Object  - Model thing, this might be the reason, why I'm confused about it.

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Comment: This is such a broad post, you are basically asking how an MVC framework works. Sure, Laravel has its own methods, but they don't differ drastically from other MVCs except in syntax. You need to read the Laravel tutorials and learn from the ground up. An answer to this question pretty much would be just a link to the Laravel documentation (which is what somebody did below)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this series https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

The `Eloquent` tutorial: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/8

The directory structure will probably be a little bit different as it is a slightly older version of `Laravel` but it will get you started.

Hope this helps!